# Cheap RFID tracking to log entry and exit?

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, rfid

I am performing an experiment where I want to track entry and exit of insect from a small opening over time. My goal is that each insect will have a tag and each pass through will ping the reader to log when the insect has entered or exited the location. This is outdoors and I will need ~5-6 of these.

Is there a cheap setup I can better understand to achieve the above task?

Comment: google `arduino RFID`

Comment: How big are your bugs?  Can they even carry a typical RFID tag or chip?

Comment: They would be carpenter bees, so not huge, but not microscopic either.

Answer (score 1):

In the first instance if you've never done a project like this, you need to learn the basics of RFID, in particular the different kinds of tags: if you have mismatched tags and readers it won't work.  Some tags support writing, some do not; there are various radio frequencies in common use.

Most people start with either

- very cheap MF RC522 board (search for `13.56MHz SPI RFID MF RC522` on Ebay) and an Arduino, or
- a USB-interfaced reader and a laptop
- NFC tags and a suitable phone

In your case I would recommend the microcontroller version as it's the cheapest and you can put an oscilloscope wherever you want.  It's easy to play with and find out all the practical things you'll need to understand such as practical range and general "fussiness".
If you search on ebay for `animal rfid` you'll find many tags and readers.  The tags for insertion into animals are normally in glass tubes, the smallest of which is about 1.5 x 8 mm, which is I expect too big and heavy for the average bee.

The main difficulty is getting the tags small enough to go on a bee, which I understand is typically 13 mm long.

Things others have tried:

- The first referenced paper uses 500μm square tags which are powered by laser pulse.  (I didn't know about those either!)  p-Chips from PharmaSeq.
- Another uses 4 mm round tags from Invengo.
- Another paper used modified QR codes 2.1 mm square
- Alibaba shows lots of results for `nfc213 5mm`, which looks very promising

So,

- **If your project is about bees**, you'll have to solve that.  The first paper ("Automated montoring...") has a review of about a dozen other projects for tagging bees.
- **If your project is about automated tagging**, perhaps you can select another animal.

Once you've got animals with tags, then you need to figure out the mechanical parts of getting the animals close to the reader.  If you can't mechanically force them to go past one by one, you'll need a reader which can read multiple cards at once.  (Some RFID technologies have a mechanism for the reader to silence responders in a structured way, in order to read multiple cards in a single place.)

---

Paper with laser-activated RFID:

- "Automated monitoring reveals extreme interindividual variation and plasticity in honeybee foraging activity level" https://lab.igb.illinois.edu/robinson/sites/lab.igb.illinois.edu.robinson/files/inline-files/TenczarEtAl2014.pdf
- Supplier: http://mail.pharmaseq.com/technology/

Paper with QR-type coding:

- "Automated monitoring of behavior reveals bursty interaction patterns and rapid spreading dynamics in honeybee social networks"  https://www.pnas.org/content/115/7/1433
- Supporting information https://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/suppl/2018/01/26/1713568115.DCSupplemental/pnas.201713568SI.pdf
- Data http://www.beemonitoring.igb.illinois.edu/
- Software https://github.com/gernat/btools

Paper with 4mm tags

- "Honey bees increase their foraging performance and frequency of pollen trips through experience" https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-019-42677-x
- RFID Supplier https://channel.invengo.com/rfid-product-line/tags-inlays-comsumables/

Answer (score 0):

No, certainly there is no cheap/out-of-the-box setup for this task.

Your idea seems possible to realize, but be aware that this needs extensive tests and design.

The basic desing steps would be as following

- Find and evaluate, or design, a tag that is as large as possible, but also small enought to fit on the bee and not harm or irritate the bee. Also a solution for mounting the tag will be requiered.
- Design and evaluate a custom reader antenna to fit around a tube where the bee passes through.
- Test if there is collision of tags when multiple bees are around/near the reader.

For desinging custom readers you need special measuring devices.

My advice is to get knowledge of RFID technology and experiment with a standard kit and different tags to understand how RFID works.

Also, it seems that University of Illinois has done [something similar.](https://news.illinois.edu/view/6367/204553)
Maybe it would be an idea to ask them for details of their project.